# jquery chained animation with appendTo()

Tags: jquery

On my page I have multiple div's with the class name *course*. Then there is one div by itself with the id *dateForm*.

What I want to do is append `dateForm` into whatever instance of a *course* div that I click on. What it should do is fadeOut from its current location, move (appendTo) to its new location and then fadeIn.

However, it ALWAYS appends itself to its new location, then fades out and fades back in. Any idea why the chain isn't working? I've tried delays, I've tried moving appendTo into another method and calling it on the callback of fadeOut, but nothing works. I even tried inserting an alert() after fadeout, but the alert() message appears before the fadeOut function even runs. Any ideas?

```
          $(".course").click(function () {
            $("#dateForm").fadeOut("slow").appendTo($(this)).fadeIn("slow");
          });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) returns immediately, before the animation has finished.  You should use the callback argument to run code after the animation is complete:

```
$('.course').click(function(e){
    $("#dateForm").fadeOut("slow", function() { // code to run after the fadeOut is complete
        $(this).appendTo(e.target).fadeIn('slow');
    })
});
```

Comment: Wow, that totally works. I never had the function(e) part before, but I had made my own function, inserted my appendTo into that function, and called that function on the fadeOut callback, but that hadn't worked. Thanks!

Comment: @kd7iwp You were probably using `this` still. Within the `fadeOut` callback, `this` is the element being faded, not the element clicked.

Comment: you're right, I was referring to the wrong instance of $(this). Thank you.

Comment: I had to change to e.currentTarget instead of e.target in order to have it append at the end of my div.